# Crete AWS Cloudwatch rule for task exist codes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I have created two AWS CloudWatch triggers for same AWS ECS Fargate task. These triggers shall be invoked when the task exited successfully, or exited with error exclusively, but now, both of them are invoked if at least one container in the task exited with non-zero error code:

The simplified task definition (The only thing you may have to note is that I have 3 images):

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                   = var.module_name
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"

  runtime_platform {
    operating_system_family = "LINUX"
    cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
  }

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name  = local.images.db
    },
    {
      name             = local.images.engine
    },
    {
      name             = local.images.test
    }
}
```

Rule targets successful exiting:

```
{
  source      = ["aws.ecs"],
  detail-type = ["ECS Task State Change"],
  detail = {
    taskDefinitionArn = [<task_arn>]
    lastStatus        = ["STOPPED"],
    containers = {
      name = [local.images.test]
      exitCode = [{
        anything-but = 0
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Rule targets successful exiting:

```
{
    source      = ["aws.ecs"],
    detail-type = ["ECS Task State Change"],
    detail = {
    taskDefinitionArn = [<task_arn>]
    lastStatus        = ["STOPPED"],
    containers = {
          name = [local.images.test]
        exitCode = [0]
    }
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me, how what did I wrong?

Again: the goal would be to have two triggers, one for task exited successfully, the other for task exited with error

Comment: So you have three containers as a part of the same task definition?

Comment: Exactly: the aim of this task is to run integration tests, so it includes 1 database container, 1 tested service container and 1 test executor container.
The alarms should be triggered on this last container's status

Comment: I can't see anything you're doing wrong, and according to the EventBridge pattern matching docs it should not be behaving this way. Perhaps there is a bug in EventBridge? You might be better off just sending all the `"ECS Task State Change"` events to a Lambda function and performing your own pattern matching in the Lambda code.